# How to find an element by text and use isPresent() for a non angular application using protractor?

Tags: angularjs, iframe, protractor

I have an iframe inside an angularjs application. I am switching to the iframe using switchTo().
I need to get the table first which has the value I'm looking for. I need to get the Yield total from within the table. I need to find the yieldtotal  inside the table using cssContainingText() beacuse the attributes for everything inside the table are the same. The yield total may or may not be present. I used yieldTotal.isPresent() but it throws an error saying "window.angular is undefined. It may be because it is not an angular application"

I cannot use browser.driver.findElement because I cannot find elementbytext that way.

```
function verifyGrossInvoiceTotal(){
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.driver.switchTo().frame('viewDocumentInFrame');
 var ProductTable = $('table.invoice-details'));
    var sum = 0;
    var YieldTotal = ProductTable .element(by.cssContainingText('td', 'Yield Total')).element(by.xpath('..'));
    **YieldTotal.isPresent()**.then(function (isPresent){
    if(isPresent){
       var totalAmount = YieldTotal .$$('td').get(3);
       totalAmount.getText().then(function (text) {
           text = parseFloat(text.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')).toFixed(2);
           sum = parseFloat(sum) + parseFloat(text);

       });
   }
   });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because `td` is not directly under `ProductTable`. Can you try something like below? Basically `'table.invoice-details td'` CSS means, find any `td` *anywhere* under `table.invoice-details`

```
function verifyGrossInvoiceTotal(){
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.driver.switchTo().frame('viewDocumentInFrame');
    var sum = 0;
    var YieldTotal = element(by.cssContainingText('table.invoice-details td', 'Yield Total'));
    YieldTotal.isPresent().then(function (isPresent){
    if(isPresent){
       var totalAmount = YieldTotal .$$('td').get(3);
       totalAmount.getText().then(function (text) {
           text = parseFloat(text.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')).toFixed(2);
           sum = parseFloat(sum) + parseFloat(text);

       });
   }
   });
});
```